# getExtras from widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have 2 buttons on my widget.
I've added `putExtra` different boolean flags to both.
I'm trying to parse `getExtra` in main activity.
But when I tap on any of them they do absolutely the same (it's not what I'm expecting).

Look at code below, what i'm doing wrong?

Part of code from `mainActivity`

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        //called when the activity is relaunched by a new intent
        setIntent(intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }



@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    Intent testI = getIntent();
    Bundle test = testI.getExtras();
    if (test != null) {
        boolean select = test.getBoolean("selectcontact",false);
        if (select == true) {
            pickContact();
        }
    }
}
```

part of code from `AppWidgetProvider` (`onUpdate` function)

```
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ctxt, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("selectcontact", true);
        mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, mainIntent, 0);
        widget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonAddwidget, pendingIntent);

        Intent mainIntentE = new Intent(ctxt, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentE = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, mainIntentE, 0);
        widget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonEditwidget, pendingIntentE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// replace this code
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    Intent testI = getIntent();
    Bundle test = testI.getExtras();
    if (test.getBoolean("selectcontact",false)) {
            pickContact();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dynamo I've renewed the  code and it not helped please check the new code.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2 intents you are using the same ID. 
Try use different ones:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, mainIntent, 0);
PendingIntent pendingIntentE = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 1, mainIntentE, 0);
```